# How to: implementation problem with Position control on a 3 Wheels robot (2 motorized) with velocity profile of trapezoid

Tags: arduino, pid, wheeled-robot, pwm, precise-positioning

I'm trying to apply position control in a wheeled robot, controlled by an arduino mega.
The robot has two wheels powered by two dc motors (1 motor for each wheel) and one castor wheel.
In order to implement the position control, I'm using classic PID control applied to each wheel seperately.
My goal is to achieve some accuracy of moving and of course that the robot is moving in straight lines when told so (this means the wheels
shall spin with the same speed, for the same distance and at the same time - otherwise the robot, would of course, turn).
Following, I have gathered how I try to do this, some issues I face and some questions that I would like to ask.

The way I'm trying to achieve these robot functionalities is the following:

- the error feeded as input to the control unit is estimated by the position generated from a trajectory profile that i wish the robot to follow,
  minus the actual position the robot has actually travelled.
- afterwards, the output of the control is fed, in the form of pwm value, from the arduino to the motor controller,
  which i guess is (something similar to) an h-bridge.
- about the desired position: as mentioned i have made a trajectory generator function.
  This trajectory is actually the integral of a trapezoid velocity profile.
  The desired position (des_pos) is actually a function of the pwm value, that i send from the arduino to the motor controller board.
  For example, for the accelerating phase, the position is calculated from the formula: 0.5(vmax/tacc)t^2 , where tacc is the time of acceleration.
  and vmax is the pwm value.
- about the actual position: the encoder provides feedback of the position of the motor. This information is translated into actual (centi)meters
  that the robot has travelled (using the diameter of the wheel and the total number of ticks per revolution generated by the encoder)

Issues:

- the des_pos as said is a function of pwm. That means that its units are not meters. Which in principle is wrong.
  To make things worst, the error is computed between dissimilar quantities..
  My idea was that I could either try and make some tests and map different values of pwm to the corresponding velocity of the robot.
  Then, by interpolation I could transform pwm values to velocity.
  Another option is to "absorb" this error inside the values of the gains. In other words, that during gain tuning I would be able to make this issue
  "hide".
- the robot in order to move in the ground, where is placed, requires a threshold pwm value. Otherwise, if less pwm value than the threshold is
  provided then the robot can not start moving. This is perfectly normal, since friction, dynamics of the motor etc are opposing the movement.
  When applying PID though, the output of the control has to be mapped to produce values of "pwm adjustment" with respect to this minimum pwm value.

Questions:

- What is the proper way to implement position control here?
  What is the "proper" approach in this kind of robots?
  My approach has many issues (see above) and it seems like gain tuning is tough.
- How can I handle the issues I mentioned or what is the best practise?
- The response I get from testing the aforementioned setup is that the motors are doing an interrupted movement.
  In other words, it seems like the robot alternates between 0 and minimum pwm value, instead of progressively increasing speed.
  Theoritically, is this a result of bad pid tuning? Or is it because of the minimum pwm value required to ignite movement in the robot?
- Something different, but more general let's say, regarding control theory.
  My understanding is that velocity and position control are actually different sides of the same coin.
  If I am not mistaken, the main difference has to do with the feature (velocity or position) which we pay attention in
  [for example in position control, you can manage the same result with velocity control - meaning you reach the same distance -
  but you have overshooting and all aspects of control focused on position whereas in velocity control you have focused on velocity], as mentioned also
  here.
  Also, what is the case when you need to take into account the dynamics of the motor? Or in other words, when is it necessary to insert the dynamics of
  the motor inside the control scheme?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.
I m looking forward to any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long post that's a bit all over the place, but as concisely as I can:

You say,

> Issues: the des_pos as said is a function of pwm. That means that its units are not meters

but you also say,

> about the desired position: as mentioned i have made a trajectory generator function. This trajectory is actually the integral of a trapezoid velocity profile.

This doesn't make sense to me - if you have a desired position, then that should determine the velocity trapezoid. If you have a velocity trapezoid driving the desired position, then you don't really have a desired position, you have a desired velocity and whatever position you get from that is incidental.

Regardless, you go on to state:

> the position is calculated from the formula: 0.5(vmax/tacc)t^2 , where tacc is the time of acceleration. and vmax is the pwm value

If you want engineering units, you should have `vmax` as a real speed, which means you need to calculate motor top speed, gearbox ratio, wheel diameter, etc.

The rest of your questions all seem to revolve around issues with PWM control, so I'll put it like this: Your vehicle controller (as described) should generate a trapezoidal speed profile, in some kind of engineering unity like meters per second.

You can use a PID controller at each wheel that accepts the trapezoidal speed control as an **input**. You can *calculate* wheel speed with wheel radius, gearbox ratio, and motor speed. The wheel speed **error** is reference (input) minus feedback (calculated). The wheel speed error is what you pass to the PID controller; P term acts directly on that error, take the integral of the error for the I term, take the derivative of the error for the D term. Take those outputs, (kP*error) + (kI*error_integral) + (kD*error_derivative), and send that out as the PWM signal. Any scaling that needs to happen for PWM will be taken into account when you do your tuning.

I would also *highly recommend* using a **feed-forward** term in your controller. This will take a bit of study on your part, but pay attention while you're doing your tuning and you should be able to plot PWM signal against steady-state wheel speed. The feed-forward "controller" will use this curve to send the estimated PWM signal to the motor directly, and the PID controller then only has to act to make up for dynamics and disturbances. I guarantee you'll get *significantly better* performance with feed-forward control than with pure PID, because PID can only ever act on an *error* - PID controllers won't send anything until you're failing to match the reference input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding the des_pos: The code expects the user to feed the robot with some des_pos which the robot shall travel. Based on this, I pass traj.generator parameters in order to achieve this. When the velocity profile is integrated, a s-curve type profile is created, which is the position over time. The position after t_final - that is the total time to elapse for the speed to become again 0 - must have reached the desired position. Since my goal is that the robot reaches the desired position, it feels to me better to feed the pid with position and not velocity.

Comment: From your answer I understand that both in position and velocity control (that you described), the control output's unit - which I consider a problematic issue - is handled by the tuning of the gain (this is what i understand from what you refer to as scaling). 
Alright, this seems fair but that also makes tuning a little bit difficult in my opinion.

Comment: Regarding PWM issues:
The ignition of the movement still troubles me. Maybe you have some comment about it?
As said in the original post, this issue is normal - and should be expected - but in the practical world, it gives me trouble. Maybe I need more testing with the robot and then come back. Right now all I am doing to overcome this is to map (with interpolation) the control output result into some value with specific limits. Shall I try something different?

Comment: Regarding the feed forward control:
If you can shed a little bit more light here, I would appreciate it. The idea is that i must have a plot of PWM-speed curve which will feed the feed-forward control (as well as in the classic PID control). The classic PID remains the same and in its output I add (or multiply?) estimation of the PWM? This estimation is based on what?
Also, can this be utilized in position control as well?
Certainly, I need to study more feed-forward control, but any simple explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking, shall I expect that this scheme of control is going to be effective or not? I mean is this some approach other engineers follow?
Lastly, I would like to ask if you agree with the following:
It seems to me that it is not a good practice to avoid making this PWM-speed curve and trying to "fix" everything with the tuning of the gains.

Thanks in advance - I truly appreciate your feedback - and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @maneedos - As concisely as I can put it: PWM modulates current to the motor - it regulates **torque**, not **speed**. Any control scheme built around PWM as an input will fail to deliver what you want because PWM doesn't mean speed. The only exception would be if you had an electronic speed controller (ESC), but then that's what I'm proposing here - build a speed controller and pass your inputs to that. The total control signal would be the sum of the PID speed controller and the feed-forward speed controller.

Comment: The feed-forward controller is one that doesn't use feedback, so yes you'd plot **steady-state** speed at 10% duty cycle, 20%, etc. Then, when you get a speed reference input to go 3 meters per second, you go to your duty cycle/speed data, interpolate the duty cycle to get 3 meters per second, and send that PWM value **and the output of the PID controller.** The feed-forward control gets immediate response in the ballpark-correct value, and that leaves the PID controller to make up for disturbances. This will give you much better response over a wider range of speeds than PID control alone.

Comment: Thanks again @Chuck. Forgive my ignorance and persistence. Just trying to learn.
Well, angular speed is proportional to torque. And torque is proportional to current. Then shouldn't it be similar?
Moreover, based on the fact that my main concern is about achieving accuracy in reaching position, what is the trade-off (if there is one) if I switch to velocity control?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding feed-forward controller. I didn't understand why you said it doesn't use feedback. But I understood that you suggested to set the PWM value as:
PWM=u+ff_pwm. Where u is the output of the classic pid (with velocity as input) -in order to handle the disturbances as you described them - and ff_pwm is the estimation based on the PWM-speed curve.
Did i get it right?
Seems nice approach, but again the gain must be carefully tuned otherwise the u value can ruin everything.
Thanks again!

Comment: @maneedos - angular *speed* is not proportional to torque, angular *acceleration* is, same way force is proportional to acceleration for linear systems. Moment of inertia or mass are the constants of proportionality. You can use velocity or position control, but I think velocity control gives better performance. Try both! See what you prefer :) And yes, you got the u+ff correct. You'll always have to tune a PID controller, but feed forward is proactive and makes up the bulk response, leaving PID primarily for disturbances, which should be more consistent across a range of speeds. Best of luck!

Comment: oups..my bad! of course torque is proportional acceleration. My mistake.
Thanks for all the help.
Although I am still confused about why achieving better results in terms of accuracy of the positioning is going to happen from velocity control+feed forwrad than in a scheme where position+feed forward control is implemented. 
As you said most probably I will have to try it.

What about the overcome of the PWM threshold value in order to make the robot move, though. Is all I can do better tuning? Or do I miss something?

Thanks again for your valuable replies!

Answer (score 0):

> The desired position (des_pos) is actually a function of the pwm value, that i send from the arduino to the motor controller board.

As you've described it, the output of the PID loop is not desired position, but rather something akin to torque. It's not exactly torque since you would need to measure current to get torque. It's not exactly velocity either since your profiler works on position. But PID out most certainly is not desired position. Desired position comes from the profiler. The PID is generating the 'effort' the motor puts into minimizing position error.

In any case, **I see nothing wrong with your approach**. It will not provide you with very high performance but should be effective. I have had projects that worked well using the same simple approach you're discussing.

NOTE: before someone points out that having your error generated against position profile sould be considered velocity since the same math is getting done but just in different places...I agree in advance.  There is a fine line and it could be considered velocity, even though the velocity went into generating the profile instead of coming out of it.